# C++ calculation of long long with int

Tags: c++, long-long

below you can find a part of my C++ code of a box class.
When I want to calculate the volume for

`l=1039`
`b=3749`
`h=8473`

I am expecting 33004122803.
Unfortunately I do not understand why only the first implementation (CalculateVolume1) gives the correct answer.

The other two calculations result in -1355615565.
Can someone please help me to understand why this is the case?

```
    class Box{

    private:

    int l,b,h;

    public:
    //works
    long long CalculateVolume1() { return (long long) l*b*h;} 
    // does not work
    long long CalculateVolume2() { return long long v = l*b*h;} 
    //does not work
    long long CalculateVolume3() 
    { 
    long long v = long long (l)* long long(b)* long long (h);
    return v;
    }
    };
```

Comment: *"The other two calculations result in -1355615565"* They shouldn't compile. (2) for sure, and (3) is, I think, would only be accepted by MSVC (incorrectly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first one, `(long long) l*b*h`, the cast applies to `l`, as if it had been written `((long long)l)*b*h`. So `l` gets converted to `long long`. And since one of the factors in the multiplication is `long long`, the other two are promoted to `long long` and the result of the multiplication is correct.

"Fixing" the syntactic errors in the second and third,

```
long long v = l*b*h;
```

here, the type of all three factors is `int`, so the multiplication is done on `int`s, and the result overflows.

```
long long v = (long long)l*(long long)b*(long long)h;
```

this is essentially the same as the first: all three factors are promoted to `long long`, this time by explicit casts on all three, so the result is calculated using `long long` arithmetic, and the result fits.

The problem with the second one as written is that you can't define a variable inside a `return` statement. So

```
return long long v = l; // illegal
```

should be:

```
long long v = l;
return v;
```

The problem with the third one as written is that a function-style cast has to have a name that's a single word:

```
long long v = int(l); // okay, but pointless
long long v = long long(l); // error, invalid name
```

could be:

```
typedef long long my_type;
long long v = my_type(l); // okay
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations!